# How do we know which methods are inherited and which are not in autocompletion in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

When I'm looking for a method of an object that I don't know, I used Xcode's autocompletion. The problem for me is that there are tons of methods that appear and most of them are inherited methods that make it harder for me to find methods proper to the object I'm working on.

Is there a way (other than going to the declaration code of the object) to make it clearer like an option to sort the methods first by inherited/locals and then alphabetically?

Comment: Look at the documentation.

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean? Which part of the documentation?

Comment: The documentation for the class whose method you want to invoke.

Comment: Hmm okay. I was just hoping there was a quicker way than this. Thanks anyway

Comment: If you type the first few characters of the method you want it thins things down quite a bit.

Comment: Yes I know that but it's more like when I have an idea about what I'm looking for but don't know the exact spelling. As I come from Java, I'm used to the setters and getters and methods are called differently but use often the same keywords.

Comment: That's why you refer to the documentation.  I use it all the time when working in Java as well.